# Can argo be used without cluster-admin role?

Tags: kubernetes, argoproj

We are users of a distributed multi-institution cluster who want to use Argo to facilitate workflows. We have a namespace in that cluster under which we create our jobs, which we currently do through `kubectl`. We do not have `cluster-admin` role, as the cluster is not even owned by our institution.

Is there a way we can use Argo workflows under our own namespace without `cluster-admin`?

If the answer is no, is there a way that the cluster admins can install Argo such that each namespace (namespaces = different institutions) don't have dependencies/conflicts with each other?

The [getting started guide](https://argoproj.github.io/argo/quick-start/) doesn't seem to mention this. I just see a `cluster-admin` assumption and that makes me think Argo isn't suited for our use case. But it's best to ask.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding YOURNAME-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=YOUREMAIL@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argo has two ways of installing, one with cluster-admin privileges and one with namespace-level privileges.

Checkout the [install guide here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/tree/master/manifests) and the [docs](https://argoproj.github.io/argo/installation/).

If you can create Roles and RoleBindings in the namespace where you want to deploy Argo you should be fine, but you will be limited to that namespace.

```
kubectl create ns argo
kubectl apply -n argo -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo/stable/manifests/namespace-install.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Argo-CD allows for a namespace install, but it still needs CRD install and i don't know any provider that open CRD installation without cluster-admin rights.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You should add more details such as sample of your code and your execution log as it will help us help you. You can also take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it will help you understand how to properly ask a question :)